# How to use websocket in spring boot and react js?

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, websocket

I referred to this [spring boot doc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) to create web socket in spring boot.

I used [stompjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stomp/stompjs) and [sockjs-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sockjs-client)

```
var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
//gives an error in below line
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
    setConnected(true);
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
        showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this [stompjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stompjs) and [socket-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sockjs-client)

then import them

```
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import Stomp from 'stompjs';
```

to connect websocket

```
//use your link here
var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:8102/api/ws');
let stompClient = Stomp.over(sock);
sock.onopen = function() {
  console.log('open');
}
stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
   console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
   stompClient.subscribe('/topic/public', function (greeting) {
     console.log(greeting);
     //you can execute any function here
   });
});
```